# Why are pages from two separate sites being indexed together?

Tags: node.js, nginx, hostname, google-index

I have an issue where pages from two distinct websites are being indexed by Google as one site.

So, we have two websites; let's call them siteone.com and sitetwo.com. When I do a search like "site:sitetwo.com" I get a few SERP pages of results, all **appearing** as from the www.sitetwo.com domain.

However, some of the results are actually content from siteone.com. These pages exist on siteone.com, but do not on sitetwo.com. If requested, they return a 404. As an example, there may be a page in the results such as "http://www.sitetwo.com/foo/bar" but that page doesn't exist and never has. The page "http://www.siteone.com/foo/bar does exist.

The websites are on the same server, at the same IP address. Sitetwo.com has been up for about a week.

Stack is: CentOS, NGINX, Node.js, MySQL. The sites are in separate directories, running separate instances of Node, and while both DBs are on the same MySQL server, they are separate DBs. The only thing they share is the server and the IP. I've included a portion of my nginx.conf file as this is, IMO, the most likely place I could've messed up.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  siteone.com;
    return       301 http://www.siteone.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  sitetwo.com;
    return       301 http://www.sitetwo.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    listen       [::]:80;
    server_name  sitetwo.com www.sitetwo.com;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/\*.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9002;
        proxy_pass_header X-CSRF-TOKEN;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }
}

server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       443 ssl;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  siteone.com www.siteone.com;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/nginx/www.siteone.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/nginx/www.siteone.com.key;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/\*.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9001;
        proxy_pass_header X-CSRF-TOKEN;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }
}
```

The "\" in "include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;" is not really there, but it was affecting StackOverflow's formatting.

Comment: Do you have any canonical meta tags set?

Comment: @Gary siteone.com is a Ghost blog (similar to WordPress) and each page has it's own canonical tag. sitetwo.com is rolled from scratch and only the homepage has a canonical tag. On both sites the tags appear correct and there is no text with the other site's domain name in the response HTML on any page of either site.